# What’s better than a hyperdrive for intergalactic travel?

Tags: space-travel, faster-than-light

I’m trying to write a Star Wars story about someone who figures out a way to travel FTL between galaxies. Hyperspace doesn’t work in the Intergalactic Void, and there is a hyperspace disturbance at the edge of the galaxy blocking travel anyway. I was trying to think of an alternative method of traveling the distance. This drive I envision could ONLY be used in the intergalactic void (so it can’t replace hyperdrive). It allows travel through the void very quickly but NOT instantaneously and there is a weird quantum glitch where the inhabitants of the ship need to wait 2 hours before piercing the veil of another galaxy or weird quantum things could happen to their ship.

Anyway I originally thought of a superfluid vacuum drive but I did a lot of research and it’s unlikely the universe is a superfluid. I know Star Wars science is soft as a marshmallow but I want some fake science that sounds realistic. Can anyone help me? I can’t think of anything.

Wormholes already exist in Star Wars.

Comment: Hi Max. We don't so much do fake science as real science, but you might get some suggestions that fit the bill anyhow in the hypothetical vein. Please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] as and when for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: *"Star Wars science is soft as a marshmallow"* A more correct comparison would be that the core of a neutron star is to marshmallows as marshmallows are to the science in Star Wars.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you're asking about a world that has already been built instead of asking about building a fictional world.

Comment: It would be WarpDrive ? I saw a show called black matter that have some kind of device that creates an artificial, instantaneous wormhole. The show described it as folding 2 coordinates to become one and creating a tear in space. It's really similar to teleporting but it can be used for great distance ( galactic distance ).

Comment: Borrow stargates made by 3rd party greater extinct dissapeared civ. With SW setting u just need form and function, so science is irrelevant. Stargates which autoconnect closest galaxies (by proximity) and do not have dial functions, someting like that

Comment: "*fake science that sounds realistic*" is usually called *technobabble*. This is not a great place to ask for plausible technobabble, since plausibility is the writer's task (not ours). Audiences *want* to suspend disbelief for a well-told story. Some of the best stories don't bother to explain lots of crazy stuff, and happy audiences don't care.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. -- Actually, I'd argue that worldbuilding in general is often full of fake science. OP is clearly in the right place for fake science!

Comment: OP -- the obvious answer here is to [go to plaid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP6DXoNKITc).  Otherwise, I really have to concur with @sphennings -- you're asking how the Star Wars universe works. That would be the domain of the [Sci-Fi and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) forum. Here we're tasked with and enjoy helping folks like you working out issues you're having with your own fictional world!

Comment: @elemtilas it got closed as off-topic for the sci-fi stack and basically deemed to belong in this stack

Comment: Apparently, [intergalactic travel is possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lWj.png) in SW. Perhaps Sci-fi & Fantasy didn't like your fanfic perspective. You could try asking in the Speculative Science forum at Codidact.

Answer (score 3):

**Additional spatial dimensions.**

As a mental aid, here is a sketch of myself.  I wish to travel to point X.

[image: me]

But as things stand I must walk across the intervening distance and the only exercise I get is in the gym.

If my 2 dimensional plane exists in a 3dimensional space such that in the 3d dimension I am very close to my destination, I can cut through the third dimension back into my own 2d plane and be where I want to go.   An infintesimally short jaunt through the third dimension and I am there!

[image: fold]

Likewise in your world if your 3d universe is topologically configured in 4 dimensions such that there is a short 4d path between origin and destination, you can travel a very short distance and be where you want to be.

"But!!", you protest.  "But what if there is no 4d plane in which my 3d planes are folded correctly?"  Then you will need to look at ways to fold the 4d planes containing your 3d plane through the 5th spatial dimension such that you are adjacent to your dimension, and you travel through a 5th dimensional space to arrive at your goal.  And this is possible for the 6th, and 7th and nth spatial dimension.    You find a higher space in which your 3d world is folded correctly.

It is turtles all the way down in this world.  The many turtles which might be necessary to make your jump is the reason for the 2 hour wait.  The [computers which calculate reentry into our 3d plane](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/206192/how-long-can-it-really-take-to-calculate-a-hyperspace-jump/206198#206198) need time to make the caluclations.  Your crew plays a lot of cribbage during these hours and they have a posted chart where they tally wins and losses against each other.

Answer (score 2):

### Time travel.

The existence of faster than light travel implies the possibility of time travel.

As such, have them simply time travel a million years into the past and then fly at near light speed in real space to their target. Droids and stasis pods can keep them alive.

You can say temporal paradoxes and the force prevent this from being a useful method with their current technology, but outside the galaxy where the force and interacting objects are less common it's fine.

After their quantum drive makes the journey they need to wait two hours past their start time, or temporal paradoxes cause crazy stuff to happen.